# Convert PNG files with transparency to WebP using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I have a utility class that loads image files and, among other operations, converts them to other formats. It uses PHP GD.

Everything works fine except PNG files that have transparency are done wrong when converting to WebP. The result image has a black background where the transparency should be.

This is my code:

```php
class OImage {
    private ?GdImage $image      = null;
    private ?int     $image_type = null;
    
    public function load(string $filename): void {
        $image_info       = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->image_type = $image_info[2];

        switch ($this->image_type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: { $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF: {  $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);  }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG: {  $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);  }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_WEBP: { $this->image = imagecreatefromwebp($filename); }
            break;
        }
    }
    
    public function save(string $filename, int $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, int $compression=75, int $permissions=null): void {
        switch ($image_type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: { imagejpeg($this->image, $filename, $compression); }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF: {  imagegif($this->image,  $filename); }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG: {  imagepng($this->image,  $filename); }
            break;
            case IMAGETYPE_WEBP: {
                imagepalettetotruecolor($this->image);
                imagealphablending($this->image, true);
                imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
                imagewebp($this->image, $filename);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (!is_null($permissions)) {
            chmod($filename, $permissions);
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

The class has many other functions to resize or scale, but are not related to my problem here. I have tried setting `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` to true or false with the exact same outcome.

I was also thinking on switching to Imagick, but they don't have yet a PHP 8 extension.

I am using PHP 8 on Debian 9 and GD 2.2.4

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: The following one-liner converts a PNG with alpha to a WEBP with alpha, without any issues:

`imagewebp(imagecreatefrompng('https://maxcdn.icons8.com/office/PNG/512/Science/alpha-512.png'), 'out.webp');`

Based on that, my guess is that some of your resize or scale operations are removing the alpha channel before you are calling `save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Thanks @msbit, I was calling to resize on my tests, as I supposed that code was ok... and it wasn't  The resize function used to be:

```php
    public function resize(int $width, int $height): void {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }
```

Now I have added an if to check if it is a PNG or WebP so this is the result:

```php
    public function resize(int $width, int $height): void {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        if ($this->image_type === IMAGETYPE_PNG || $this->image_type === IMAGETYPE_WEBP) {
            imagealphablending($new_image, false);
            imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
            imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
        }
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }
```

Now everything works flawlessly

Thanks!!